# Trees and dates

Tags: real, sequence

A friend of mine in Sydney, Australia, asked for help in explaining these stones. I don't know if this is really a puzzle, but he's definitely puzzled.

> In one of our local parks someone has put stones round some of the
>   trees
>
> I can't work out if the dates, if that is what they are intended to
>   be, relate to

And he follows up with the date-like inscriptions (Australia uses dd-mm-yyyy) on the 12 stones round one tree:

> 3.6.2050
>
> 27.2.2050
>
> 14.8.2051
>
> 21.7.2052
>
> 26.3.2053
>
> 29.5.2054
>
> 1.2.2055
>
> 23.5.2056
>
> 8.6.2057
>
> 20.8.2057
>
> 24.8.2058
>
> 3.7.2059

[image: Stones with engraved numbers surrounding a tree]

Comment: Maybe it's similar to what Terry Pratchett's [Counting Pines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flora_and_fauna_of_the_Discworld#Counting_pines) do?

Comment: But seriously, he indicates that this is just the list of numbers (dates) from one tree, yet there are many. Do they all end in 2050? Does the middle number indicate January, April, Sept, Oct, Nov and Dec in those? or are all of them just months 2,3,5,6,7,8?

Comment: Finally! A post revealing someone from Ostraylia! :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like this is

> an art project called [Time Rings](http://www.cityartsydney.com.au/artwork/time-rings/)

It says

> "The dates were chosen using a random selection of birthdays from the children of nearby Annandale Public School, forging a powerful connection between the artwork and the local community."

Answer (score 2):

My only thought is that:

> They're 50 year anniversary markers of some event.
>  It seems plausible that they were created in the 2000's